# Placing divs on same line

Tags: html, css

Ok so I'm trying to set up 5 divs to come up in the shape of a 'W'. check out my sight to get a reference of what I mean here: http://joshadik307.github.io. Right now I am using a table but that is not effective because it is not doing exactly what I want and will cause problems when I try to reformat everything to work on different screen sizes.

Anyways, on my site there are 5 divs in the shape of a W just underneath the header. I want to have those so that they always show a perfect W (IE each of the divs is always evenly spaced between the two above or below it) and so that the W stretches as the screen size is expanded.

Comment: Add your code here...

Comment: I would but I used tables in my code and I was hoping to find a way to get the same result without tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline block - the misunderstood and under-appreciated display type:

```
<div class="w-wrapper">
 <div class="callout">1</div>
 <div class="callout">3</div>
 <div class="callout">5</div>
 <div class="callout">2</div>
 <div class="callout">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.w-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

.callout {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
    margin: 2em 5%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/jq6eyud2/

Comment: Wow, I can't believe the solution was so simple! Thanks!

Comment: Haha sorry I'm new around here

Comment: One more question, right now the 'W' isn't quite centered, it's a little to the right of the page. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response.  The fiddle I posted above is perfectly centered, as can be seen in [this updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanwheale/jq6eyud2/2/).  This new fiddle has extra styles so you can see the centering, and I left a comment where you can play with the values to fine tune it for your specific scenario.  It's likely that a parent DIV has some extra padding on the left but not the right.  Give me a link.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create four equal width dives

2- float them left

3- Create equal sized divs in each div with required margins

for example in the first div margin top will be 0 and in the second div margin top will be maximum and so on....